# Using the flutter_barcode_scanner package, how can I scan for PDF-417 only?

Tags: flutter

I am successfully scanning PDF-417 (US driver's license) data with the flutter_barcode_scanner package.  The problem is that driver's licenses have two barcodes;
one that is PDF-417 and one that is not.  Sometimes the phone camera scans the correct barcode, and sometimes it scans the wrong barcode.  How can I get my code to only scan the PDF-417 barcode and ignore the other one?

Comment: I guess you cannot stop the scanner from scanning without manipulating the internal code of the package. Best way is to let it scan but compare the outputs, so if the output is PDF-417 then go on else show a prompt.

Comment: Thanks or the suggestion Krish.  There are two options.  1.  Scan once, return a result and stop. 2. Scan continuously and return results via a stream.  I would have to analyze the results being returned from the stream to see if the right data format is being returned and then stop the stream.  I would prefer using an existing API call, but if that's not possible I might pursue this option.